# thead/tbody spanning on multiple pages of printed HTML but NOT on the first page

Tags: html, css

Is there a css approach for doing this.  either with 'running' or other css.  I want to print a HTML document and have thead/tbody to span multiple pages.  But I don't want to display the header on the first page.

Keywords I used to google
css thead tbody page print

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure there's really a viable way to do this. HTML/css are by nature page-less: they don't have any knowledge or support for pages.

Or.... then again, maybe there is some support. 
 You can specifiy [page breaks](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/pagebreak.shtml). Here's the [w3schools reference](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_ref_print.asp).

Comment: There is thead/tbody that spans multiple pages and I believe like y ou said, page-breaks and running and other tags with the new CSS.